# How to display nested JSON objects with a changing string in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, nested

Got a very hard problem to solve and no clue how to tackle it. I'm coding in Angular 6.

To my problem, this is my JSON file. I can easily access data like `"id"` or `"certificate`. But I want to display the nested `remainingCounts` which are left on the ticket and here comes the next problem: the ID before the number of the `remainingCounts` always matches to the `appointmentTypeIDs`. How can I tell my Angular Frontend to display always all data icluded in the `remainingCounts` array?

```
[
   {
      "id":9073111,
      "certificate":"A4245322",
      "productID":425193,
      "appointmentTypeIDs":[
         5780379
      ],
      "remainingCounts":{
         "5780379":10
      }
   },
   {
      "id":9073113,
      "certificate":"0BE0C148",
      "productID":435370,
      "appointmentTypeIDs":[
         5780416
      ],
      "remainingCounts":{
         "5780416":50
      }
   },
   {
      "id":9073115,
      "certificate":"E72984C2",
      "productID":435376,
      "appointmentTypeIDs":[
         5780421
      ],
      "remainingCounts":{
         "5780421":100
      }
   }
]
```

My certificate.ts:

```
export class CertificatesComponent implements OnInit {
  private certificates: Array<object> = [];
  pageTitle = 'Meine Zertifikate';
  email = this.auth.userProfile.name;

  constructor(
    private title: Title,
    private apiService: APIService,
    public auth: AuthService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.title.setTitle(this.pageTitle);
    this.getData();
  }

  public getData() {
    this.apiService
      .getCertificatesByUser(this.email)
      .subscribe((data: Array<object>) => {
        this.certificates = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
}
```

Any my HTML template:

```
<div class="ui cards" *ngFor="let certificate of this.certificates">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="header">{{certificate.name}}</div>
          <div class="meta">{{certificate.email}}</div>
          <div class="description">
            Verbleibende Termine Ihrer {{certificate.name}}-Karte:
            <span *ngFor="let remainingCount of certificates.remainingCounts">
              {{remainingCount}}
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <sui-progress class="bottom attached indicating active" [value]="80"></sui-progress>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all **`remainingCounts`** is not an array as per the JSON data you've provided. It's just another object.

You could just display using `dot(.)` Operator as you do it for other properties without **`ngFor`**

```
<div class="ui cards" *ngFor="let certificate of this.certificates"> <div class="card"> <div class="content"> <div class="header">{{certificate.name}}</div> <div class="meta">{{certificate.email}}</div> <div class="description"> Verbleibende Termine Ihrer {{certificate.name}}-Karte:  {{certificate.remainingCount}}  </div> </div> <sui-progress class="bottom attached indicating active" [value]="80"></sui-progress> </div> </div>
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oocxgw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: this results in a `[object Object]` on my template. :/

Comment: Yes because it's an object, if you need to display whole object use |Jon pipe as {{certificate.remainingCounts | json}}

Comment: thanks my man. can you give me any approach how to visualize the the remainingCounts object in a more beautiful way? will try to solve the rest...

Comment: what do you mean by more beautiful way

Comment: It is display like this: `{ "5780379": 1 }` - is there a way to remove the curly brackets and only display the number after the ID, like `{{certificate.remainingCounts.5780379}}`? But this doesn't work.

Comment: yes do this    {{certificate.remainingCounts[certificate.appointmentTypeIDs[0]]}}

Comment: if not work {{certificate.remainingCounts.5780379}} try {{certificate.remainingCounts['5780379']}}

Comment: @Eliseo OP needs to do this dynamically i guess